# How to run a function over a group in R

Tags: r, grouping

I have a data table with that has a series of stocks, dates and prices.  I am trying to calculate the return of the stocks over a given interval of time (say 3 days).

```
stocks <- c("AAPL", "GOOGL", "AAPL", "GOOGL", "AAPL", "GOOGL","AAPL", 
"GOOGL")
date <- c("2017-05-15", "2017-05-15","2017-05-16","2017-05-16","2017-05-
17","2017-05-17","2017-05-18","2017-05-18")
price <- c(1.5, 1.75, 1.55, 1.7, 1.45, 1.75, 1.6, 1.7)
table <- data.table(stocks, date, price)
```

I also have a function that calculates returns for a given asset:

```
getReturn <- function(vector, n=2) {

  num.rows <- nrow(vector)
  output.range <- 1:(num.rows-n)

  buy.price  <- vector[output.range,3]
  sell.price <- vector[output.range+n,3]

  returns <- data.table(log(sell.price) - log(buy.price))
  returns <- cbind(vector[output.range,],returns)
  names(returns) <- c("stocks", "date","price","return")

  return(returns)

}
```

If I apply this function on each asset individually, I can calculate the 2 day return.  But how would I apply this function to each asset such that the results are the 2 day return of each specific asset?

```
b <- subset(table, stocks == "AAPL)
getReturn(b)

   stocks       date price      return
1:   AAPL 2017-05-15  1.50 -0.03390155
2:   AAPL 2017-05-16  1.55  0.03174870
```

My actual data set is much larger, so subsetting the two securities and rebinding them is not a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `by` that subsets a dataframe by one or more factors in this case, *stocks*. The return is a list of whatever your function returns equal to number of factors. And since you pass one factor, it returns a named list: `b$APPL`, `b$GOOGL`, etc.

```
b <- by(table, table$stocks, FUN=getReturn)

b

table$stocks: AAPL
   stocks       date price      return
1:   AAPL 2017-05-15  1.50 -0.03390155
2:   AAPL 2017-05-16  1.55  0.03174870
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
table$stocks: GOOGL
   stocks       date price return
1:  GOOGL 2017-05-15  1.75      0
2:  GOOGL 2017-05-16  1.70      0
```

Do note this is a base R solution and not `data.table` solution, so you can use `data.frame()`.

And to generate a single data.frame, simply run `do.call(rbind, b)` on list of dataframes:

```
finaldf <- do.call(rbind, b)
rownames(finaldf) <- NULL   # RESET ROWNAMES

finaldf
#   stocks       date price      return
# 1   AAPL 2017-05-15  1.50 -0.03390155
# 2   AAPL 2017-05-16  1.55  0.03174870
# 3  GOOGL 2017-05-15  1.75  0.00000000
# 4  GOOGL 2017-05-16  1.70  0.00000000
```

Comment: Thank you- that looks like it works well, but is there a way to make that return a single dateframe (or datatable)?

Comment: Sure. Simply `do.call(rbind, b)` since b is a list of dataframes, append all elements together! See update.